# Error on dropping pandas dataframe row using boolean condition indexing

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, boolean

I'm trying to remove rows from a dataframe if a particular column value does not appear in a previously defined dictionary

```
dff= dff[dff['network'] in net_dic]
```

Each value of 'network' is a string. and net_dic looks like this:

```
{ 'abc' : 1
  'def' : 2
. 
. 
.}
```

It errors:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: Show us a sample of your dataframe and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this works:

```
dff= dff[dff['network'].isin(net_dic.keys())]
```